# Setting a deadline for 2 items using calendar and validate the date?

Tags: java, performance, validation, calendar, client-server

I want to create a server which should accept 2 input times (each for an item) and display when the item's deadline has been reached.

---

Here's what the program should do:

- Ask for deadline time for item 1
- Set deadline for item 1
- Ask for deadline time for item 2
- Set the deadline for item 2
- Run server, checking that the deadline has not been reached. If reached, display the appropriate message in the console to say which deadline has been reached (for which item).

I am struggling with being able to implement this with my code.

---

Here's what I have right now:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MultiEchoServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        int date = start.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int month = start.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = start.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Socket client;
        ClientHandler handler;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");

        System.out.print("Enter finishing time for item 1 in 24-hr format "); // Item 1
        System.out.print("(e.g. 17:52) :  ");
        String timeString = input.nextLine();

        String hourString = timeString.substring(0,2);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);

        //Extract minutes from user's entry...
        String minString = timeString.substring(3,5);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(minString);

        //Set up Calendar object to hold deadline time...
        Calendar deadline = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Put current date (retrieved from 'start' Calendar object) and time (entered by user) into above
        //Calendar object...
        deadline.set(year,month,date,hour,minute,0);
        //(Last argument above specifies seconds.)

        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline: " + getDateTime(deadline) + "\n");

        System.out.print("Enter finishing time for item 2 in 24-hr format "); // Item 2
        System.out.print("(e.g. 17:52) :  ");
        String timeString2 = input.nextLine();

        String hourString2 = timeString2.substring(0,2);
        int hour2 = Integer.parseInt(hourString2);

        //Extract minutes from user's entry...
        String minString2 = timeString2.substring(3,5);
        int minute2 = Integer.parseInt(minString2);

        //Set up Calendar object to hold deadline time...
        Calendar deadline2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Put current date (retrieved from 'start' Calendar object) and time (entered by user) into above
        //Calendar object...
        deadline2.set(year,month,date,hour2,minute2,0);
        //(Last argument above specifies seconds.)

        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline: " + getDateTime(deadline2) + "\n");

        //Retrieve current date and time...
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();



        while(now.before(deadline) || now.before(deadline2))
        {
            //System.out.println(getDateTime(now));

            //Pause to prevent dates and times from
            //scrolling off screen too quickly...
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException intEx)
            {
                //Do nothing.
            }

            //Update current date and time...
            now = Calendar.getInstance();
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline reached!!!\n");

        do
        {
            //Wait for client.
            client = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
            handler = new ClientHandler(client);
            handler.start();
        }while (true);

    }

    public static String getDateTime(Calendar dateTime)
    {
        //Extract hours and minutes, each with 2 digits
        //(i.e., with leading zeroes if needed)...

        String hour2Digits = String.format("%02d", dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        String min2Digits = String.format("%02d", dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        return(dateTime.get(Calendar.DATE) 
                + "/" + (dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) 
                + "/" + dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) 
                + "  "+ hour2Digits + ":" + min2Digits);
    }   
}


class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
    private Socket client;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintWriter output;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
        client = socket;

        input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String received;

        received = input.nextLine();
        while (!received.equals("QUIT"))
        {
            output.println("ECHO: " + received);
            received = input.nextLine();
        }

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
            client.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("* Disconnection problem! *");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of setting the deadline for each item and checking whether the deadline has been reached? Would creating a class for the `Item` be a good idea? How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an inconsistency in the design of the server side. The logic that compares the `Calendar` objects should ideally be in the `ClientHandler` thread, not in the `main` method. Otherwise there would be no meaning for the `ClientHandler` (which the way it is written in your code does nothing but create a client socket and then closing it).

Concerning the logic itself, if you're limited to using the `Calendar` API, then there is very little you can do to reduce the verbosity. However, your code does not consider the day, month and year when comparing the current time to the deadline.

If this is what's expected, i.e. the server essentially assumes the deadline is on the same day then you don't need to set the date in the created calendar object. Only set the hour and the minute:

```
deadline.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
deadline.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

You may also want to include seconds to be more precise.

If you are using Java 8, then the [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#compareTo-java.time.OffsetTime-) may come in handy for a few reasons:

- It represents a time (without the need to specify a date).
- It includes an offset that represents the time zone in case your client and server are in different time zones.
- It is thread-safe.

You can use the input string to create an object as follows:

```
OffsetTime deadline = OffsetTime.parse("10:15:30+01:00");
```

And you can compare to other time objects using the method [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#isBefore-java.time.OffsetTime-).

If the date should be considered, then you can use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).